# React Native iOS Release build crashing

Tags: react-native

When releasing the iOS build, it kept on crashing on the QA's iPhone without any error message. There was no error message while building either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to create a new main.jsbundle file while keeping the --dev tag as false instead of true.